# inverse argument for interpolation

Tags: real-analysis

From interpolation we know that if $f\in L^p$ where $2\leq p\leq \infty $, it can be written as $f=f_1+f_2$ where $f_1\in L^2$ and $f_2\in L^\infty.$ I'm wondering what can we say about the other direction. That is, if we have $f_1\in L^2$ and $f_2\in L^\infty,$ is it true that $f_1+f_2 \in L^p$ for some $2\leq p\leq \infty?$ And what is the relationship between $p$ and $f_1,$ $f_2?$ I tried to show it's true but not yet successful. I'm not sure how to bound a sum's $L^p$ norm using the conditions. Could I ask for some help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If $f_1=0$, then $f_1+f_2 =f_2\in L^\infty$ directly. Similarly for $f_2=0$

Comment: Yes, I just forget that "for some" in your question.

Comment: Then just take $f_1 = \frac 1{x^{1/3}} \chi_{(0,1]}$, and $f_2 = 1$. $f_1 + f_2$ is not in $L^p$ for all $p\in [2,\infty]$.

Comment: You're right. Thanks!